# Robot Framework having trouble evaluating expression with a colon in it

Tags: python, robotframework

I currently have a conditional statement with two variables in Robot Framework that have a colon(:) in the string. The evaluation fails every time. Both variables are strings and the same evaluation will work just fine in Python `(':00'==':00')`. I've tried an escape char `\:00`, I've also tried with just one zero `:0`.

```
*** Variables ***
${string_one}         :00
${string_two}         :00

*** Test Cases ***
Compare Two Strings
    ${type_string_one}=     Evaluate        type($string_one)
    Log     ${type_string_one}
    ${type_string_two}=     Evaluate        type($string_two)
    Log     ${type_string_two}
    IF      ${string_one}==${string_two}
        Log         Pass
    Else
        Log         Fail
    END
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The condition needs to be valid python. In your case, after the variables are substituted the expression becomes `if  :00==:00` which is invalid python.

You have a couple options. The first is to surround your data with quotes:

```
IF      "${string_one}"=="${string_two}"
```

The above guarantees a string comparison. However, if there's a chance that your data itself contains a double-quote, you'll end up creating an invalid expression.

The better solution is to use robot's special syntax that omits the curly braces. When you do that, robot will convert the robot variables to python variables, requiring no quoting at all.

```
IF      $string_one==$string_two
```

With the above, it's as if the robot variables `${string_one}` and `${string_two}` were python variables named `string_one` and `string_two`.

FWIW, this is all documented in the documentation for the BuiltIn library. See the section titled [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions)